# Using JavaScript, how do I use the .toExponential() function, but only using two decimal places (9.99e9, instead of 9.9999e9)

Tags: javascript, decimal, exponential, floor

If I have a variable that is set to 2345, and I want to convert it to exponential, I simply do variableName.toExponential().replace(/e+?/, 'e'), which will give me 2.345e3. However, I want it to only return two decimal places there, because otherwise once I get to much larger numbers, like 183947122, I'll get a long decimal, 1.83947122e8. I want this to floor to 1.83e8, but I can't figure out where I would put variable.toFixed(2) in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a regular expression and `replace` (which you're already using to replace `e+` with `e`):

```
const str = variableName.toExponential().replace(/^(\d*\.\d{0,2})\d*e\+(\d+)$/, "$1e$2");
```

That captures the whole number portion of the coefficient plus up to two fractional digits of it, ignores any others, and captures the full exponent; it replaces the match with `$1$2` so you're left with just the up-to-two digits of the coefficient:

```js
function test(variableName) {
    const raw = variableName.toExponential();
    const str = raw.replace(/^(\d*(?:\.\d{0,2})?)\d*e\+(\d+)$/, "$1e$2");
    console.log(variableName, "=>", raw, "=>", str);
}

test(2345);
test(100);
test(1019);
test(183947122);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a=1233434;
console.log(a.toExponential(2));
```

you can pass the parameter in .toExponential(2) function for rounding.it will give 2 number after decimal check this link https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/javascript-toexponential-function/

Comment: op does not want rounding.

Comment: *"I want this to floor to ..."*

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the floored value and then apply `toExponential`.

```js
const f = (x, p) => {
    const l = 10 ** (Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(x))) - p);
    return (Math.floor(x / l) * l).toExponential(p);
}

console.log(f(183947122, 2));
console.log(f(-183947122, 2));
console.log(f(183947122, 4));
```